# Строка записывается 10 раз вместо одного

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('/etc/hosts') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

str = 'Строчка'
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str))
with open('/etc/hosts', 'r+') as f:
    for line in lines:
        result = pattern.search(line)
        if result is None:
            
             f.seek(0, 2)
             f.write("This is my first line\n")
```

Вместо того чтобы в конце файла записать одну строку, скрипт записывает её 10 раз.

Comment: Надо просто сместить эту строчку кода влево, на один уровень с `for`

Comment: А почему бы не открыть на запись как `w`? Тогда, содержимое файла сотрется, а вы сможете записать как вам нужно, тем более, ранее вы все строки из файла и так считали

Comment: Которая у вас 10 раз такую и сместить на уровень for в конце